# How to show the latest modified date of any files underneath a given directory?

Tags: command-line, filesystem

As shown in this reverse chronological order listing the last file or subdirectory of '.' was modified on April 12, but the date of modification shown on the directory itself is April 17.  I would need to list the entries of folders based on the last modification date of any of the files within them (directories might be tricky..).  Is that possible to do?

```
$ ls -lrta ../hercl.src
..
drwxr-xr-x   9 steve  staff    288 Mar  8 07:48 .idea
drwxr-xr-x  15 steve  staff    480 Apr 12 16:40 .git
drwxr-xr-x  24 steve  staff    768 Apr 17 12:16 .    ## Newer than latest file modified date..
                  
So the "ask" would be to return April 12 not April 17th.
```

Comment: Have any files been deleted from that directory?  Do you have any automated processes that encrypt/unencrypt directories?  In answer to your second question, yes you could write a shell script to loop over the directories and display the latest last-updated time of any file in them.

Comment: @dg99 I don't have any processes that are en|de-crypting, and do not recall having done anything to delete .  I am writing a python script now to get what is needed

Comment: Your question title asks something else than the last part of your question itself: are you wondering why the date is different than expected or do you need to get some specific information?

Comment: Yes I am wondering why the dates are different than expected.

Comment: The simplest reason might be that a file has been removed from ../hercl.src, or that the directory entry itself was modified. But nevertheless, both the second part of your question and your python script have a different focus than explaining why the dates might differ.

Comment: The modification date of a directory is the date when something changed in the directory file itself : directory file changes when a file is added, removed or renamed. If a file is modified the directory containing it will not be set as modified as the directory file is not modified.

Comment: @nohillside  OK I will divide into two questions.   This one is updated now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a utility to descend sub-directories and extract the newest date of a modified *file* and then use that date to represent the overall ancestor directory.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
def lsd(fname):
    def lsdRec(fname):
        from pathlib import Path
        from operator import itemgetter
        import os
        fpath = Path(fname)
        fs = list(fpath.glob('*'))
        if not fs:
            return []
        else:
            def getLast(lst): 
                x = lst[-1] if lst else [None,0]
                return x

            def getModified(fpath):
                try:
                    return os.path.getmtime(str(fpath.resolve()))

                except Exception as e:
                    print(f"Error on {fpath}: {e}")
                    return 0

            fl = sorted([ getLast(lsdRec(f)) if f.is_dir() 
                else [f,getModified(f)] for f in fs],key=itemgetter(1))
            return fl
    rst = lsdRec(fname)
    from datetime import datetime
    outLst = ([ [ str(x[0])[len(str(fname))-1:], 
        datetime.fromtimestamp(x[1]).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')] for x in rst])
    out = '\n'.join(['\t'.join([x[1],x[0]]) for x in outLst])
    return out

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print(f"sys.argv {sys.argv}")
    print("""
Usage: lsd <directory>

Prints the files and subdirectories according to last modified date of contents
""")
    sys.exit(1)

dir=sys.argv[1]
print(lsd(dir))
```

The output shows the file within each subdirectory that has the newest modified date . So the output shows the whole path including subdirectories. I like this!

```
2022-03-07 16:40:48 x/hercl-0.3.2/setup.cfg
2022-04-20 16:15:25 x/y/z/zz/thereThere
```